# SQL 2005: Agent job step output file naming

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know, please, if there's a way to specify "this machine" in a file path that SQL Server will like?

I have an Agent job I want to script onto all my servers. It outputs to a file on the local machine so I want to script the file name as

```
\\localhost\<shared-folder-name>\<file-name>
```

Another reason is I'm planning to use log shipping for disaster recovery and I want the jobs to work the same whichever server they're running on. The script sets the job up fine but when I run the job I get an error "Unable to open Step output file". I think I've eliminated share and folder permissions: it works fine with `C:\<folder-name>\<file-name>`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried @@SERVERNAME?

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

Or you can use this, the second one you can use if you have multiple instances of SQl server running

```
SELECT serverproperty('MachineName'),serverproperty('Instancename')
```

Comment: Thanks, Menace, but the problem is I'm talking about the job step's results output file that you specify in Management Studio. Plus I want the string to be the same on all servers in case I have to fail over to my standby server.

Answer (score 0):

When you script it out
You can utilize the `@output_file_name` parameter

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name = @JobName01, @step_name = @JobName01, 
@subsystem = 'CMDEXEC', @command = @JobCommand01, @output_file_name = @OutputFile
```

To set the output log name, we can do

```
SET @OutputFile = @LogDirectory + '\SQLAGENT_JOB_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTDT))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTTM)).txt'

To get the server name
$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the folder in the same location on all machines.

c:\SharedSQLLogFiles.....

If you don't want them in the same location, create a Junction C:\SharedSQLLogFiles pointing at the actual location.

In this way you can simply script the file location as a local path, but still be able to access the file from a remote share.

Cheers, Ben